# Init Dropzone.js inside fancybox/ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, fancybox, dropzone.js

I'm trying to create kind of a Mediacenter where you can click on a button and then the "Mediacenter" opens via ajax inside a [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/). 
There it shows all uploaded images (until here it works great) and as well a possibility to upload new images. Therefore I'd like to use [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/).

Inside the ajax/fancybox I tried to add a dropzone-form:

```
<div id="dropimg"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("div#dropimg").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });
});
</script>
```

But all id does is adding a new class `dz-clickable` to my div. Not the Dropzone Form.

```
<div id="dropimg" class="dz-clickable"></div>
```

So it means the dropzone.js and jquery is implemented and works, but somehow not everything. When I add the code directly into the `<body>` of the page, it works perfectly. But not in the ajax/fancybox.

Does anybody know why?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you create a test page or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

on ajax the dropzone.js is lost for some reason, I have faced such a problem with many jquery plugins

I resolved this problem by,
on the success callback I've reattached the script and then call the .dropzone safely

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#loadedFormId').load('url',
                    function(response, status, xhr) {                           
                            requireJs('dropzoneScript', '../../../../Scripts/Dropzone/dropzone.min.js', function() {
                                console.log('dropzone is alive');
                                $('#dropzoneForm').dropzone();
                            });
                        }
                    });
            });
```

and the requiredJs function is a js function which will redownload the script file for you

```
function requireJs(scriptId, file, callback) {

    var element = document.getElementById(scriptId);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

    var script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
    newjs = document.createElement('script');
    newjs.setAttribute('id', scriptId);
    // IE
    newjs.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (newjs.readyState === 'loaded' || newjs.readyState === 'complete') {
            newjs.onreadystatechange = null;
            callback();
        }
    };
    // others
    newjs.onload = function () {
        callback();
    };
    newjs.src = file;
    script.parentNode.insertBefore(newjs, script);
}
```

it looks like a weird solution but it worked for me ... enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! In the requireJs-Function you have a `scriptId`. What is this?

Comment: actually this is what makes the solution wired, I gave the script an id to remove and re-append  on demand, on our case the demand is ajax success callback 
i.e. `<script id="dropzoneScript" src="~/Scripts/Dropzone/dropzone.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Ah ok. I tried it and now i get `dropzone is alive` in my console, but it still does not load the whole form. It only adds the class..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, N0rA. But I "solved" it by avoiding AJAX. I created the media-center as a hidden div and I opened it as a Inline-Fancybox. This way the Dropzone.js works great.